# Why is $\pm\sqrt{(11y-8)^2} = \pm(11y-8)$? - Analytic Geometry

Tags: quadratics, conic-sections, radicals, absolute-value, square-numbers

$3x^2-7xy-6y^2-2x+17y-5=0$

My original goal here was to know whether or not this was a degenerate conic, so I isolated $x$ by applying the Quadratic Formula.

$3x^2+(-7y-2)x+(-6y^2+17y-5)=0$

$x = \frac{-(-7y-2)\pm\sqrt{(-7y-2)^2-4(3)(-6y^2+17y-5)}}{2(3)}$

**a)** $x = \frac{(7y+2)\pm\sqrt{(11y-8)^2}}{6}$

It is to my understanding that an expression of the form $\sqrt{x^2}$ is equal to $|x|$ for every $x$ $\in$ $\Bbb{R}$, which is why I expect **a** to become

$x = \frac{(7y+2)\pm|11y-8|}{6}$

and so yielding two equations

**b)**$$x = \frac{(7y+2)+|11y-8|}{6}; x = \frac{(7y+2)-|11y-8|}{6}$$

However, my book does not include the absolute values, $\sqrt{(11y-8)^2}$ simply becomes $11y-8$

[image: img0]

giving

**c)**$$x = \frac{3y-1}{6}; x = \frac{-2y+5}{3}$$

Moreover, each equation in **b** and **c** have different graphs, but coincide when combined. What am I missing? **Why do we get rid of the absolute value?**

---

---

I think this is because of the $\pm$ in the Quadratic Formula. My computations are as follows:

$$x = \frac{(7y+2)\pm|11y-8|}{6}$$

By definition of absolute value,

**Case 1 $+$**

$$x = \frac{(7y+2)+|11y-8|}{6}$$

Let $11y-8\geq 0$ $\implies y\geq\frac{8}{11}$ $\implies x\geq\frac{13}{11}$ ,

$$x = \frac{7y+2+11y-8}{6}$$
$$x = 3y-1$$
$$y = \frac{x+1}{3}$$
$$\frac{x+1}{3}\geq\frac{8}{11}$$
$$x\geq\frac{13}{11}$$

Let $11y-8\lt0$ $\implies y\lt\frac{8}{11}$ $\implies x\gt\frac{13}{11}$,

$$x = \frac{7y+2-11y+8}{6}$$
$$x = \frac{-4y+10}{6}$$
$$x = \frac{-2y+5}{3}$$
$$y = \frac{5-3x}{2}$$
$$\frac{5-3x}{2}\lt\frac{8}{11}$$
$$x\gt\frac{13}{11}$$

This means we can write $x = \frac{(7y+2)+|11y-8|}{6}$ as the combination of $y = \frac{x+1}{3}$ and $y = \frac{5-3x}{2}$, with $x\geq\frac{13}{11}$ and $y \in \Bbb{R}$ because $y\geq\frac{8}{11}$ or $y\lt\frac{8}{11}$.

The graph looks like this:

[image: img1]

**Case 2 $-$**

$$x = \frac{(7y+2)-|11y-8|}{6}$$

Let $11y-8\geq 0$ $\implies y\geq\frac{8}{11}$ $\implies x\leq\frac{13}{11}$,

$$x = \frac{7y+2-11y+8}{6}$$
$$x = \frac{-4y+10}{6}$$
$$x = \frac{-2y+5}{3}$$
$$y = \frac{5-3x}{2}$$
$$\frac{5-3x}{2}\geq\frac{8}{11}$$
$$x\leq\frac{13}{11}$$

Let $11y-8\lt0\implies y\lt\frac{8}{11} \implies x\lt\frac{13}{11}$,

$$x = \frac{7y+2+11y-8}{6}$$
$$x = 3y-1$$
$$y = \frac{x+1}{3}$$
$$\frac{x+1}{3}\lt\frac{8}{11}$$
$$x\lt\frac{13}{11}$$

This means we can write $x = \frac{(7y+2)-|11y-8|}{6}$ as the combination of $y = \frac{x+1}{3}$ and $y = \frac{5-3x}{2}$, with $x\leq\frac{13}{11}$ and $y \in \Bbb{R}$.

The graph looks like this:

[image: img2]

This means we can write $x = \frac{(7y+2)\pm|11y-8|}{6}$ as the combination of $y = \frac{x+1}{3}$ and $y = \frac{5-3x}{2}$, with $x \in \Bbb{R}$ because $x\geq\frac{13}{11}$ or $x\leq\frac{13}{11}$, and $y \in \Bbb{R}$.

In other words,

We can think of $x = \frac{(7y+2)\pm\sqrt{(11y-8)^2}}{6}$, which is $x = \frac{(7y+2)\pm|11y-8|}{6}$

[image: img3]

as $x = \frac{(7y+2)+|11y-8|}{6}$ and $x = \frac{(7y+2)-|11y-8|}{6}$

[image: img4]

or as $y = \frac{x+1}{3}$ (purple) and $y = \frac{5-3x}{2}$ (orange)

[image: img6]

Note: I used *GeoGebra* for the graphs.

---

---

If my analysis is correct, is there any reputable sources (or proof) that says we can simply cancel out under these circumstances?

$$\pm\sqrt{(11y-8)^2} = \pm(11y-8)$$

Comment: Please correct your title, adding the missing parentheses.

Comment: @Intelligentipauca Done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question essentially reduces to $\pm |x| = \pm x$. Note that $\pm x$ isn't really a value but rather the set $\{x, -x\}$, so we want to show $\{|x|, -|x|\} = \{x, -x\}$. This is simple casework:

- If $x > 0$, then $LHS = \{x, -x\} = RHS$.
- If $x = 0$, then $LHS = \{0\} = RHS$.
- If $x < 0$, then $|x| = -x$, and $LHS = \{-x, x\} = RHS$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Shouldn't it be $\{0,0\ }$ instead of just $\{0\}$?

Comment: @Nameless Sets don't contain duplicated elements. You want to look at the range of values it can take. So e.g. $x_1,x_2=\frac{1\pm\sqrt{0}}{2}$ then you can just write $x_1=x_2=\frac{1}{2}$.